# How to edit wordpress post without republishing

Tags: archives, rss, feed, publish, quick-edit

Is there a way to update an older post without republishing the post?

If I am looking at a previously published post and discover a misplaced comma or reformat an image I don't need all my RSS and email subscribers to receive that post in their feed. This is especially an issue if I want to fix issues in multiple posts on the same day.

I saw something somewhere about changing the post to private, saving, and then setting the post back to public but that seems to also require publishing to reset the post.

Answer (score 0):

No... Your users won't receive the post again in their feeds when you click `update` button. That's how WordPress works.

So don't be afraid to click `update button`

> Dashboard -> All Posts -> Edit -> Make changes -> Click update button

PS: If you still afraid, do a little experiment.

By default your feed url looks like this.

```
http://yourwebsite.com/feed/
```

Go to that url. Note the first 5 feed url.

Now edit the post of your 2nd feed url, make some changes and click update button..

Visit your feed page again. See.. Your post not appearing again.